# Why use Crank-Nicolson over Matrix Exponential when solving Schrödinger's equation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, computational-physics, algorithms

For Schrödinger's equation,

$$\psi(x,t+\Delta t)=e^{-i H\Delta t}\psi(x,t)\approx\frac{1-\frac{1}{2}i H\Delta t}{1+\frac{1}{2}i H\Delta t}\psi(x,t).$$

The right-most expression is the [Crank-Nicolson scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crank%E2%80%93Nicolson_method) for solving the system. However, it is only an approximation of doing matrix exponentiation.

A lot of literature (or course notes online) that I find seem to use the Crank-Nicolson scheme instead of computing $e^{-i H\Delta t}$. Is there some benefit to using the approximation given by the Crank-Nicolson scheme over doing a matrix exponentiation?

It seems to me that even if numerical algorithms to compute matrix exponential (such as [`scipy.linalg.expm`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.expm.html) ) use a higher-order Padé approximation - this would still be preferable to the Crank-Nicolson scheme.

Comment: A very simple reason is: Although it’s great for finite dimensional systems, it’s extremely difficult in position representation or at least no less difficult than crank Nicholson

Comment: If you can exponentiate your Hamiltonian in reasonable time and storage, then by all means use it. In this case your $\Delta t$ has no restrictions like being small enough. But more often you can't due to the size of the matrix.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is hard to compute matrix exponential. And the Crank-Nicolson approximation of evolution operator has at least two advantages besides simple enough computation. Asymptotic equalities
$$
1-iH\Delta t = e^{-iH\Delta t} + O\left( \Delta t^2\right),
$$
$$
\frac{1-\frac12iH\Delta t}{1+\frac12iH\Delta t} = 1 - iH\Delta t - \frac{\Delta t^2}2 H^2 + O\left( \Delta t^3\right) = e^{-iH\Delta t} + O\left( \Delta t^3\right)
$$
demonstrate the first one. The second advantage is strict unitarity
$$
\left(\frac{1-\frac12iH\Delta t}{1+\frac12iH\Delta t}\right)^\dagger = \frac{1+\frac12iH\Delta t}{1-\frac12iH\Delta t} = \left(\frac{1-\frac12iH\Delta t}{1+\frac12iH\Delta t}\right)^{-1},
$$
in opposition to approximate one
$$
(1- iH\Delta t)^\dagger = 1 + iH\Delta t = (1 - iH\Delta t)^{-1} + O(\Delta t^2) \neq (1 - iH\Delta t)^{-1}.
$$

Addition. I am not a computational physics specialist, so I can only suppose what is the actual reason why the Crank-Nicolson approximation is used. Not always you need or can have matrix written in computer memory. Sometimes you only have a procedure that computes matrix action on vectors. In such cases, computations of higher degrees of $H$ involved in the Pade approximation might be undesirable.

Comment: Padé approximation used to compute the matrix exponential also seem to produce unitary matrices.

Comment: I admit my answer might not contain the actual reason why the Crank-Nicolson approximation is used. I only highlighted some of its interesting properties.

Comment: @XYZT The Crank-Nicholson scheme *is* a Padé approximation to the matrix exponential. If you use a numerical method which has higher order accuracy than the order of the PDE, you are likely to introduce spurious numerical solutions which cause instabilities. That is why the common RK45 4th-order method is only conditionally stable for first or second order equations, for example. Crank-Nicholson is unconditionally stable.

Comment: I doubt that the original motivation for the Crank-Nicolson (*not* Nicholson) scheme come from the matrix exponential. It is a scheme developed for the integration of the heat equation. Given the similarity if the heat equation with the Schrodinger equation in the x representation it was natural to use it for the S.E. as well.

Comment: @alephzero I doubt that is the reason. Any explicit scheme is only conditionally stable, even 1st order Euler or 2nd order RK.

Comment: How do you compute the inverse? I thought inverse is about O(n^3) same as exponentiation.

Comment: @lalala There are various techniques, depending on whether the system is dense or large-sparse, but in both cases I would estimate that the inverse is 1-2 orders of magnitude faster than the exponential.